# DocumentDb REST Permissions and Resource Tokens

Tags: rest, azure, permissions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a read only permission for an entire collection. My server retrieves the permission for the user and associated resource token, sends it down to the client (phone) app and the phone app can then retrieve some documents on it's own.

Should be straightforward.

According to the [create a permission link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt632102.aspx) in the Azure docs, the documentation says this:

> The full addressable path of the resource associated with the permission. For example, dbs/ruJjAA==/colls/ruJjAM9UnAA=/.

But the sample shows this:

```
{
"id": "a_permission",
"permissionMode": "Read",
"resource": "dbs/volcanodb/colls/volcano1"
}
```

And the sample is clearly ID based as is the rest of my project.

FWIW, I tested both and if you create a permission based on id, like the sample, you get a forbidden response.

If you create a permission with the full resource, then it works fine.

Hope my full day's worth of sorting that out helps someone.  :)

And I know someone will get bent if I don't actually post this as a question, so here's my question:

Is this an error in the documentation, or an oversight in the code, a future enhancement or an online testimony to my noobness because I did it all wrong somehow?

TIA.

Comment: Yep good spot - I found the same, I think the docs are out of date, the id's used to work but mustve been a long time ago, I couldn't get them to work when I was playing with it.  In theory I think either id or name *should* work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the full path, like dbs/volcanodb/colls/volcano1 (no trailing slash when using name/id or dbs/ruJjAA==/colls/ruJjAM9UnAA=/ (with trailing slash when using self-link). Simply proving the name, like volcano1, doesn't work as there can be multiple volcano1 collections in an account. There's more about self-links here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear, Mimi.  I was passing the full path, one way was using self-links and the other was using all the id's (and no trailing slash).  I'll try it again just to be sure, but I think it's a bug.  I checked my test and the self-link had a trailing slash and the id path did not.

Comment: Ok, just retried all my test code.  Everything works great if I use resource id's instead of id's. And yes, I double checked the trailing slash business, even trying it with and without.  I'd like to file an issue someplace, but I don't know where the repo for the code is.  Or at least tell someone.  By the way, I'm doing all this with REST calls.

Comment: I can follow up with the team and see if we can repro. Will follow up here with the findings/explanation.

Comment: Can you post the exact request you're using? Both the id and selflink permission are working for us.

Comment: Mimi, thanks for following up, but I concluded I can't use REST calls from the client to solve my problem (it's the application, not the tech).  That means all calls need to be made from the server, where I can control security without issuing permissions to users in the wild.  I dropped all the code and testing and moved on.

Comment: How do I close this if it's not an answer?